# Client found response content type of 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, mtom, xop

When I am calling Web service method, and getting this error,

```
"Client found response content type of 'multipart/related;   
type="application/xop+xml";    
boundary="uuid:8507df24-4a53-4943-9728-3297e243ddce";   
start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>";   
start-info="application/soap+xml"', but expected 'application/soap+xml'.
```

The request failed with an empty response."

I m exacting `"application/soap+xml"` now , but
how can I get `"application/xop+xml"` response?.

I have to solve this problem,

Thanks for any advice...